# Set a python variable to the results of a SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to set a variable to the results of an SQL query, the current output I am getting is `None`

```
    c.execute("SELECT Dpos1 FROM tblRoom WHERE RoomId="+count)
    Position=c.fetchone()
    print(Position)
```

`c` is the variable used for my table, the value of `Dpos1` is the integer value I am trying to assign into the variable `Position`

This is the construction of my table.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("Rooms Table.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE tblRoom
              (Roomid INTEGER,
               Dpos1 INTEGER,
               Dpos2 INTEGER,
               Dpos3 INTEGER,
               Dpos4 INTEGER,
               Dpos5 INTEGER,
               Dpos6 INTEGER,
               PRIMARY KEY(RoomId))""")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: `c.execute("SELECT Dpos1 FROM tblRoom WHERE RoomId=?", (count,))` is the correct way of constructing the query, not string concatenation, which is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Generally I prefer to create and do a sanity check of what i am querying through my connection. In 2 steps using the format method: `sql_query = "SELECT Dpos1 FROM tblRoom WHERE RoomId={}".format(counts)`. Then `c.execute(sql_query)`